# group send failed. telegram api bot, sendMediaGroup function

Tags: php, json, telegram

in function input $files = $_FILES

Don't get what Telegram wants from me.

It says: "{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: group send failed"}". HIELPLEAS!

```
function sendMediaGroup($files)
{
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $this->token . "/" . __FUNCTION__;
    $media = [];
    $ch = curl_init();
    $type = "photo";
    $caption = "";

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $media[] = [
            'type' => $type,
            'media' => $file['tmp_name'],
            'caption' => $caption
        ];
    }

    $disable_notification = false;
    $reply_to_message_id = null;
    $parameters = [
        'chat_id' => $this->chat_id,
        'media' => json_encode($media),
        'disable_notification' => $disable_notification,
        'reply_to_message_id' => $reply_to_message_id,
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);

    return $output = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: You only passed file name, please attach that to request

Answer (score 2):

In order for Telegram to create a media group **from photo URL in the Internet**, a file link you pass as `media` attribute value must be accessible by Telegram's servers. Sometimes it is not the case and `sendMediaGroup` API call fails with the cryptic error message `Bad Request: group send failed`. In this case you can try another approach to send photos, e.g. in `text` field using [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method or go to `@webpagebot` and send him a link to your file - this will update preview for the link and you will be able to send that link inside of the media group.

Note to moderators: this answer does not 100% targets original question, but link to this question pops up in first ten while searching using words from the caption.

Comment: hmm, it helps, some file always return error "Bad Request: group send failed" until I send that link to this bot, and I can't repeat this error again with another files

Answer (score 1):

You should name your files and attach files to the request according their name. So change your code like this:

```
function sendMediaGroup($files)
{
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $this->token . "/" . __FUNCTION__;
    $media = [];
    $ch = curl_init();
    $type = "photo";
    $caption = "";
    $parameters = array();

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $media[] = [
            'type' => $type,
            'media' => "attach://" . $file['tmp_name'],
            'caption' => $caption
        ];

        $parameters[] = [
            $file['tmp_name'] => $file
        ];
    }

    $disable_notification = false;
    $reply_to_message_id = null;
    $parameters[] = [
        'chat_id' => $this->chat_id,
        'media' => json_encode($media),
        'disable_notification' => $disable_notification,
        'reply_to_message_id' => $reply_to_message_id,
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);

    return $output = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting URL for media, you URL should work on :80 or :443 port. For example: https:examplesite.com/image1.jpg is OK, https:examplesite.com:8443/image1.jpg is not OK!